# Both ISNULL and YEAR SQL functions in in Linq

Tags: sql, linq, t-sql

How can I do this in Linq?

```
SELECT [...] WHERE A.Year = YEAR(ISNULL(B.Date, '1900-01-01'))
```

data types of fields:

```
A.Year : int not null
B.Date : datetime null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ to Entities:

```
(...)
where a.year == SqlFunctions.DatePart("y", b.date ?? new DateTime(1900, 1, 1))
```

LINQ to SQL:

```
(...)
where a.year == (b.date ?? new DateTime(1900, 1, 1)).Year
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what your data structures look like on the .NET side of things...

```
var defaultDate = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);

var result = from x in xxx
             where x.Year == (b.Date ?? defaultDate).Year
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.Where( f => f.Year == (B.Date ?? new DateTime(1990, 1,1)).Year)
```